# How get mac adress of routeur if I use newlist

Tags: python, linux, networking, command-line

I write this script to get mac address of routeur when ESSID is Home

```
        proc = Popen(['iwlist', 'wlan0', 'scan'], stdout=PIPE)
        for line in proc.communicate()[0].split('\n'):
          if ' ESSID:' in line:
              intext=str(line)
              m2=search('ESSID:".*" ',intext)
              ESSID=m2.group(0).split('"')[1]
              if ESSID =="home":
                   if ' - Address:' in line: # first line in iwlist scan for a new AP
                             intext=str(line)
                             m2=search('Address: .*',intext)
                             adress_router=m2.group(0).split('')[1]
```

but I have this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "att_de.py", line 80, in <module>
routeur()
File "att_de.py", line 23, in routeur
ESSID=m2.group(0).split('"')[1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I need help please.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the final space in your `'ESSID:".*" '` is messing you up.  If that doesn't help, add a `print intext` statement in there before you hit the error and add the output to your question